# Not Change app.config

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, app-config

I want to change Connection string  at runtime in app.config

The code I wrote is as follows:

```
var config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
ConnectionStringsSection connectionStringsSection = (ConnectionStringsSection)config.GetSection("connectionStrings");
connectionStringsSection.ConnectionStrings["test"].ConnectionString = "sadasd";
//config.ConnectionStrings.SectionInformation.ForceSave = true;
config.Save();
ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("connectionStrings");
```

but app.config not change!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this method used by me and worked for me on a WinForms and MySQL Project :

```
 private void EditConString(string connName, string user, string pwd, string server,string database)
        {
            var config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
            var connectionStringsSection = (ConnectionStringsSection)config.GetSection("connectionStrings");
            connectionStringsSection.ConnectionStrings[connName].ConnectionString = "Server=" + server + ";User Id=" + user + ";password=" + pwd + ";database=" + database + ";ConnectionTimeout = 60;Allow Zero Datetime=True";
            config.Save();
            ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("connectionStrings");
        }
```

Good luck!